# TeamCity's CSS inspector does not recognize SVG elements

Tags: css, svg, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have a histogram using SVG and style it with a separate CSS file.

For testing and code inspections I'm using TeamCity 8.x. TeamCity's CSS inspector reports errors on the SVG elements I am styling. For example:

```
/* histogram */
.bar rect {
    fill: steelblue;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

This is a reported bug (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-56). Is there a way to suppress these errors *without* changing the severity of this issue for the entire project?